# Packets installed with npm wont go global

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, git-bash

I'm trying to install things with **npm** on **windows** inside **Git Bash** but the command does not become global. So if I installed **gulp** in **Git Bash** for instance :

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Running :

```
gulp
```

in the same terminal window will give me **Gulp is not an internal command**.
Does any one know what is missed, some kind of env maybe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\npm in you local environment variables should do the work. Dont forget to reopen your bash/cmd after changing the environment vars. At least this is what i got and inside the folder are the installed commands as *.cmd.

Comment: and the prize goes to @pytomaniaq! It worked magically. I beleive he meant the following : put C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\npm inside your PATH variable and restarting the git bash will fix the problem. Thank you!